# Как добавить gitbash в ConEmu?

Tags: git-bash, conemu

Почему нет gitbash в ConEmu? Хотя на компе установлен gitbash. Я же так понимаю он должен его автоматом подтягивать? Как его добавить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: переустанови gitbash и/или ConEmu, может у тебя пути не по умолчанию для баша

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо установить [GitBash](https://git-scm.com/downloads) отдельно тогда появится опция в меню выбора в ConEMU